# Fast api how to convert an string fields to list fields using get method

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, api, fastapi

How Convert an string field to  List fields using get request. Here is my current response look like:

```
[
  {
    "title": "My first blog ",
    "body": "Hello world ",
    "image_url": "https://image1.png,https://image2.png,",
    
  }
]
```

I want to convert my image_url field like this `"image_url": [https://image1.png,https://image2.png,]` here is my code:

```
@router.get('/ads', response_model=List[schemas.ShowBlog])
def all_publish_blog(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    blogs = db.query(models.Blog).filter(models.Blog.is_published==True).all()
      
    if blogs:
        return (blogs)
```

so my api response will be look like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "My first blog ",
    "body": "Hello world ",
    "image_url": [https://image1.png,https://image2.png,],
    
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split() to convert your string, like that :

```
liste = [
  {
    "title": "My first blog ",
    "body": "Hello world ",
    "image_url": "https://image1.png,https://image2.png,",
    
  }
] 

new_url = liste[0]["image_url"].split(sep=",")

liste[0]["image_url"] = new_url
```

(new_url will have an empty element at the end, due to the slit but you can remove it)